# Does Relative pronoun in relative clause always follows the noun it modifies/referes?

Tags: grammar, american-english, spoken-english, relative-clauses, informal-language

I have studied about relative clauses in many blogs and i noticed in every blog that, the relative pronoun was followed by the noun it modifies, is it thumb rule of relative clause? Or any situations do exist like the relative pronoun and noun it modifies not follow immediately but are present after some statements in between?

Comment: In most cases the relative word immediately follows the head noun. But it doesn't have to. For example, it is possible for the relative clause to be **postposed**, as in "A _stranger_ came into the room _who_ looked just like Uncle Oswald", where the antecedent of "who" is the non-adjacent"stranger".

Comment: @BillJ Do you have any support? like any grammar book you are fond of?